# Hosting a WCF Web API app on AppHarbor?

Tags: iis, iis-7, appharbor, wcf-web-api

I've implemented a sample app like the one [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2011/04/21/wcf-web-api-is-pure-simplicity-with-nuget.aspx). It is a really basic app just to get things started. Everything works fine in IIS on my local machine, I've got it running on my IIS Express as well, but now come the tricky part. I do want to host this on [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/), but I get 404 error. I've started a [discussion](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/603-deploy-a-wcf-web-api-is-it-possible) on the support forum of AppHarbor, and they have taken a screen shot of the error when they run it. [image: ScreenShot]

It seems like it is something wrong with the routing since the StaticFile handler is used, but I'm just guessing. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try and add

```
<system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

to your web.config